# Azure DevOps Server 2022 (on-premise) AAD group members not updating?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019

We are evaluating Azure DevOps Server 2022, specifically using the Git repositories function. We require an on-premise solution due to some compliance requirements, which is why we aren't using Azure DevOps Services (cloud).

Something I can't wrap my brain around is application of new permissions. We configured some AD security groups and added to the appropriate DevOps groups. We have groups for Collection admins, project admins, build admins, and contributors. Everything looks great until we add a user to one of the groups. It seems the Azure DevOps server doesn't see membership changes until after an unspecified amount of time, sometimes as much as 24 hours.

My question is, why wouldn't group memberships be seen and applied with Azure DevOps immediately, and is there a process to force DevOps to check for and sync/refresh group memberships? Anything I find via a Google search always references Azure AD sync-related configurations, whereas our implementation is strictly on-premise using ADDS, not Azure AD.

Restarting the server and any related services.

Answer (score 0):

TFS/Azure DevOps Server use a background synchronization job, scheduled every hour, to look for changes in Active Directory (or the local machine workgroup if the server is not domain joined). So, changes you make to local or Active Directory groups do not get reflected in TFS/Azure DevOps Server immediately. Instead, TFS/Azure DevOps Server will synchronize those groups regularly (by default every hour).

You can force the job to run using any of these techniques: [How to synchronize TFS users with AD](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24305.how-to-synchronize-tfs-users-with-ad-active-directory.aspx).

It could be that you still do not see the user or name listed in the UI even if synchronization is working. The synchronization job does not automatically create a user profile in the database for every user or group in the database, to avoid useless growth in big enterprises.

In such a case, the first time you use a new AD account (user or group), you must refer to it uses `DOMAIN\account` syntax so that TFS/Azure DevOps Server look up in AD on the fly and insert a profile record in the database for the account.

Further Troubleshooting Mr. Hinsh has a good [troubleshooting guide](https://nkdagility.com/blog/active-directory-groups-not-syncing-with-team-foundation-server-2010/) if you still have troubles. It's still applied to Azure DevOps Server.